# Making this CSS work in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I am having trouble getting some styling done in IE8. This project was originally going to not be AS cross-browser enabled to go back to IE8 but now it must be, so I am trying to make the necessary changes to this CSS on this website.

This is the first page division of the site, the home section up top with a logo and sign-up box. This section has CSS that looks like this:

```
#page-div-home{
    height:auto;
    background:url('../img/_Pics/bg.png') 50% 40%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: fixed;

    .logo{
        width:100%;
        max-width:1000px;
        height:300px;
        margin-top:100px;
        display:inline-block;

        background:url('../img/_Logos/eSchoolLogo.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
        background-position: fixed;
    }

}
```

It also has media queries on the two half-page wide sections that look like this:

```
.sub-wrap{
width:100%;
max-width:1500px;
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;

@media screen and (max-width: 1340px){
    width:90%;
}

.sub-half{ //for FAQ section
    width:50%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    text-align:left; //a fix for the .sub-wrap text-align:center, all the FA
    padding:10px;

    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;

    @media screen and (max-width: 1340px){
        display:block;
        float:none;
        width:1000px;
        margin:0 auto;

        ul{
            padding:0;//this allows the <li>, when they are stacked, to take up full width of ul
        }
    }//media query(1340)

    @media screen and (max-width: 1125px){
        width:700px;
    }//media query(1125)

    @media screen and (max-width: 810px){
        width:100%;
    }

}//.sub-half
```

I am not sure what exactly, out of all the attributes used, are making IE8 render the page incorrectly(thought I guess it is rendering it correctly for its standards) but I would like to learn how to fix the things that are wrong.  I also have a `<header>` and `<nav>` tag that are used in the the top menu that is `position:fixed;` to never move on scroll.. Anyways, any help is appreciated.

Comment: There's no media queries on IE8, but there are many workarounds that you can find with google.

Comment: remove all unnecessary stuff out there, and make your question more specific, atleast include demo

Comment: Still though without even using the media queries, the header and first home section of the [website](www.domfarolino.com/eSchool) is totally crap for whatever reason

Comment: There is a demo, its the website I included

Comment: Have you checked your `js` errors on `IE8` ? I ran into couple of errors when tried to load it on `IE8`

Comment: `background-size` is also not supported in IE8 which is why your background image looks like that. There's a background-size polyfill [here](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add the following to your head section in your HTML code:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `IE8` does not support `media queries`. To run media queries on IE8 use [Modernizr](http://responsivedesign.is/resources/javascript-jquery/modernizr)

Answer (score 0):

when you use html5 tags, must add to DOM the news elements (nav, heather, footer..) with JS:

```
document.createElement("nav");
```

Or try the option of @BuddhistBeast is better